# Best method for pulling data out of SharePoint to use with a Business Intelligence application

Tags: sharepoint, cognos

I'm looking for advice from anyone out there who has experience integrating SharePoint with a business intelligence application like Cognos.

Our BI team wants to be able to report on data stored in SharePoint. Their tool of choice is Cognos. What's the best way to get the data they're looking for OUT of SharePoint and into Cognos BI for analysis?

To clarify I'm NOT looking for a way to display Cognos reports in SharePoint. We want to take the list data from SharePoint and use Cognos to report on it.

Comment: If you haven't already you may also want to ask this on Stack Overflow for some further opinions.

Comment: I'll try that out. The segregation of "Admin issues" and "Dev issues" is as annoying on these sites as it is in the industry in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a few answers over on stackoverflow.com

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442311/best-method-for-pulling-data-out-of-sharepoint-to-use-with-a-business-intelligenc